# Iterating over Multiple Lists in Python When the Lists are Different Lengths

Tags: python, mysql, for-loop, flask, jinja2

I have this table of data that I'm pulling from a MySQL database and trying to match up the rows and I am having trouble figuring out this last piece of it. I'm using Flask to pass three lists of dictionaries using 'izip_longest' to the Jinja template and then a for loop inside the Jinja template to go through the variables from each row. The problem is the three lists I'm iterating through have variable lengths and aren't always going to be the same length.

I've gotten this far as shown below, but I need the dates to match across the entire row. In this case, S-Date/07-11 should either be 07-11 across the whole row, or be blank in the other columns.

```
S-Date | S-Place | G-Date | G-Place | F-Date | F-Place
------------------------------------------------------
 07-11     7       07-12     7        07-11      7
 07-12     7       07-13     7        
 07-13     7       07-14     7
 07-14     7
```

I feel like I'm close to figuring it out but I've been staring at this forever and can't quite get it.

This is the SQL table I'm drawing data from:

```
location | date | status
------------------------
 001      07-10    success
 002      07-10    success
 123      07-11    fail
 222      07-11    fail
 333      07-11    fail
 232      07-11    fail
 444      07-12    pending
 555      07-13    pending
```

This is the query to get the number of failures for each particular day:

```
SELECT 'date', COUNT(`location`) as 'location' FROM mytable 
  WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) 
   AND `status` LIKE '%fail%' GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

This is for the number of successes per day:

```
SELECT `date`, COUNT(`location`) as 'location' FROM mytable 
   WHERE YEARWEEK(`date`, 1) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE(), 1) 
     AND `status` NOT LIKE '%fail%' GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

I need the failures and successes to match up to the day grouping so I can generate a stacked bar chart to show each number for a single date/bar.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? Any reason you can't do this with a query?

Comment: @e4c5 I'm ultimately trying to generate a stacked bar chart with one segment for "successes" and one segment for "failures". The issue with the SQL query is that sometimes there are no successes/failures and when using "group by", I can't get a 0 value to appear. Every example I've seen that's related to this problem involved doing a JOIN but I'm only using one table.

Comment: why don't you post the table let's see

Comment: @e4c5 i edited my original post with some additional info.

Comment: thanks but one more think what are S-Date, G-Date etc?

Comment: The first table I provided is a simple-view of how far I'm able to get with the data right now and to show how it's not lining up across each iteration of the-loop (one row = one iteration).

On 07-11 there were 7 scheduled locations (S-Date), but all 7 failed (F-Date / F-Place), hence the reason G-Date / G-Place don't have any data for 07-11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what all this `S-Date`, `F-Date` business is, but I think what you want to know is how many total success and failures you have for each unique date.

I have a very simple solution for you in Python:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import Counter

data = defaultdict(list)

for row in database_table:
    data[row[1]].append(row[2])

results = {}

for date, attempts in data.iteritems():
   stats = Counter(attempts) 
   results[date] = {'total': len(attempts)}
   for stat, count in stats.most_common():
      results[date][stat] = count
```

Now results is a dictionary, with the key being the date, and the value is another dictionary with all your stats. In your template you would simply:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Total Places</th>
        <th>Success</th>
        <th>Failed</th>
        <th>Pending</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     {% for date, stats in results.iteritems() %}
         <tr>
            <td>{{ date }}</td>
            <td>{{ stats['total'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ stats['success'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ stats['fail'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ stats['pending'] }}</td>
         </tr>
     {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

> One thing I'm having trouble with is the dates aren't showing in the
>   correct order. They go from 07-14 to 07-11, rather than 07-11 to
>   07-14. I know Python dictionaries are not ordered so now I need to
>   investigate how to get the dates ordered correctly.

To sort the dates, you need to convert them first to datetime objects; so that the sorting works properly.

```
import datetime

# rest of the code here

fmt = '%m-%d'
results = [] # a list, so its sortable
for date, attempts in data.iteritems():
   stats = Counter(attempts) 
   record = {'total': len(attempts),
             'date': datetime.datetime.strptime(date, fmt)}
   for stat, count in stats.most_common():
      record[stat] = count

   results.append(record)

results = sorted(results, key=lamdba x: x['date'])
```

Then, just adjust your template:

```
{% for record in results %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ record['date'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ record['total'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ record['success'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ record['fail'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ record['pending'] }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Okay I think I've got it figured out now. Doing this in Python was certainly much easier than trying to massage the MySQL query to get what I wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: One thing I'm having trouble with is the dates aren't showing in the correct order. They go from 07-14 to 07-11, rather than 07-11 to 07-14. I know Python dictionaries are not ordered so now I need to investigate how to get the dates ordered corrrectly.